# How to activate LVM on a partition mounted and used by system?

Tags: lvm

I have a cento7 distro so defined:

```
[root@vm99]# ssm list
----------------------------------
Device          Total  Mount point  
----------------------------------
/dev/sda      1.17 TB  PARTITIONED  
/dev/sda1  1000.00 MB  /boot        
/dev/sda2     1.17 TB  /            
----------------------------------
```

if i execute pvcreate /dev/sda2
  Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?

How i could activing lvm in a VPS? Really this need is born from using docker with devicemapper. 
Starting docker with devicemapper it gaves a error... so i thought devicemapper needs LVM.

Answer (score 1):

In a running system: Impossible.

You could try to do this in a rescue system with the help of a temporary block device, but just starting over and doing it right from the start is likely much easier.

Comment: so i might start from rescue system and than execute pvcreate /dev/sda2. Anything other ? No other setting? maybe in grub?

Comment: No. It's *much* more complicated then that. I won't even try to come up with a guide for this. Try googling, there is likely plenty to find on that topic.

Comment: Ok sorry last question.... it is necessary lvm for devicemapper ? My docker with device-mapper gives error... i supposed was because it dont found lvm device blocks.

Comment: This is a completely different topic.

Comment: Your easiest approach is  to shrink the filesystem on `/dev/sda2` (this is not possible with XFS, so beware), shrink the `/dev/sda2` partition, add another one in the new free space and use this as PV for LVM .

Comment: I tried but i lost all data :) uhmm old file system is no more readable. Ops